# SpringBoot + REST, Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Reason: CORS request did not succeed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a problem with CORS, but only at some versions of Firefox and Safari: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ... (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). At Chrome it's fine for all testing machines. Here's my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/some_public_urls")
    );
    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

    TokenAuthenticationProvider provider;

    public ApplicationConfig(final TokenAuthenticationProvider provider) {
        super();
        this.provider = requireNonNull(provider);
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    TokenAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, s) -> {
            // No redirect is required
        });
        return successHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Disable Spring boot automatic filter registration.
     */
    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean disableAutoRegistration(final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Each RestController is annotated with:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
```

Comment: Ok, so what's the request that failed, what was the response, and what was the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

I could guess that you are performing testing on some old browsers and it doesn't work.

[Here](https://caniuse.com/?search=cors) is the landscape of CORS support in browsers. Please check it out.

> As of mid-2014, approximately 83% of the browsers out there have full
> support for CORS, and another 6% have partial support.

If it's the case, you could try some other techniques like
[JSON-P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or using [Proxy Server](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/overview-of-proxy-server-and-how-we-use-them-in-react-bf67c062b929) to make cross-origin requests in older browser.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
It turned out, that it was certificate issue. We have a certificate bundle (wildcard certificate) and it was placed in wrong order. Some browsers could handle this, some versions of Firefox were blocking it.